# useEffect() causes infinite loops

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
React.useEffect (() => {
    if (rows.length === 0) {
        async function fetchMyApi() {
            const url = `https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2`;
            let res = await fetch(url);

            res = await res.json();

            if (res) {
                setRows (res.data);
            }
        }
        fetchMyApi();
    }
}, [rows]);
```

Calling an API inside useEffect is creating infinite loops. I have tried passing an empty array, I tried every possible solution, but no use.

Comment: the `[rows]` as the second parameter of useEffect causes it to run everytime the rows variable is changed. I assume `setRows(res.data);` is updating that value, which is causing your loop.

Comment: i want set the response to setRows , what is the possible way and the api call should be runned on page load

Comment: why does the api call require `rows.length === 0`?

Comment: i taught by using rows.length === 0 might stop re rendering

Answer (score 0):

Your `useEffect` dependencies, `[rows]`, cause your `useEffect` to refire every time you call `setRows` which is creating an infinite loop.

```
const [rows,setRows] = React.useState([]);

const fetchMyApi = React.useCallback(async () => {
        const url = `https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2`;

        let res = await fetch(url);

        res = await res.json();

        if (res){

            setRows (res.data);

        }
}, [setRows]);

React.useEffect (() =>{
    fetchMyApi();
},[fetchMyApi]);
```

In the above code the `useCallback` is not necessary as this function is not being passed to any components.

`setRows` should remain constant for the lifetime of the component.

`fetchMyApi` will be created on component mount and everytime that `setRows` changes.

The `useEffect` will run on mount and everytime that `fetchMyApi` changes. Since `fetchMyApi` will never change the `useEffect` is only run on component mount.

Comment: Check [https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gmbpgc](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gmbpgc) The console.log only runs once. If possible create a reproducible example so we can see what you are experiencing.

Comment: please have a check https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2ma5ih?embed=1&file=components/Home.jsx

Comment: on your table row you have `openProfileTab(row)` which is calling the function when it renders. This function in turn calls `handleChange` which in turn calls `setValue` which causes a rerender. The assign should look something like `onClick={(e) => openProfileTab(e,row)}`.

Comment: i hope you got my problem looking into the code, let me know if you need any more info

Comment: note when you assign functions inline they are recreated every render, when cleaning up your component you should split your tablerow view out and use a `useCallback` to ensure the function is only recreated when it is needed.